# UICollectionView reloadData has different behaviors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView, and use `reloadData` when the item number is updated.

And it work well in **iphone SE 9.3.2** by calling `numberOfItemsInSection` before `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. However, `numberOfItemsInSection` will not been called in **iphone6 9.3.4**, then will get **range exceeded exception** because UICollectionView is refreshing a cell which should be removed.

EDIT:

Found something. I have called `[self setNeedsLayout] [self layoutIfNeeded]` of a subview to update constraints before reloadData. And everything is right after remove those teo lines. **WHY**?

Comment: had same issue. Found out that collection view had too small frame so no cell was visible and `numberOfItemsInSection` wasn't called. Do you create collection view programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I make it programmatically. And when I call reloadData, collectionView is out of the bound of screen and set hidden=YES, is that the reason? But it did call numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath before reloadData. @Astoria

Comment: I think it might be the reason. Cells must be visible to get loaded.